# More than 8 map in ELM 0.19 decode

Tags: json, elm

I have flags decoder with default values.

```
flagsDecoder : Decode.Decoder Params
flagsDecoder =
    Decode.map8 Params
        (Decode.field "field1" (Decode.string) |> (Decode.withDefault) "1")
        (Decode.field "field2" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "2")
        (Decode.field "field3" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "3")
        (Decode.field "field4" (Decode.string) |> (Decode.withDefault) "4)
        (Decode.field "field5" (Decode.string)  |> (Decode.withDefault) "5")
        (Decode.field "field6" (Decode.int) |> (Decode.withDefault) 6)
        (Decode.field "field7" (Decode.string)    |> (Decode.withDefault) "7")
        (Decode.field "field8" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "8")
```

How can i add more fields? I have a JSON object with 10 fields.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I would recommend using [`andMap`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/latest/Json-Decode-Extra#andMap) from [`elm-community/json-extra`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm-community/json-extra/4.0.0/):

```elm
flagsDecoder : Decode.Decoder Params
flagsDecoder =
    Decode.succeed Params
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field1" (Decode.string) |> (Decode.withDefault) "1")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field2" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "2")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field3" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "3")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field4" (Decode.string) |> (Decode.withDefault) "4")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field5" (Decode.string)  |> (Decode.withDefault) "5")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field6" (Decode.int) |> (Decode.withDefault) "6")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field7" (Decode.string)    |> (Decode.withDefault) "7")
        |> Decode.andMap (Decode.field "field8" (Decode.string)   |> (Decode.withDefault) "8")
```

But there are also other options like [`elm-json-decode-pipeline`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/NoRedInk/elm-json-decode-pipeline/latest/) and [a new experimental API](https://github.com/rtfeldman/elm-json-experiment). `andMap` is really simple and straight-forward though, to use along with and to switch to from `mapN` if needed.